# What is vsidx in Visual Studio and why is it autogenerated?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem in visual studio, everytime i create a new repo and try to commit a bunch of files apears: .vsidx, .cahce, .props etc. I have never come across anything like this before and my question is how to get rid of these files and also why are they appearing? For your info i have Visual studio community 2022 17.3.4

Comment: These sound like auto-generated files.  You probably need to configure a .gitignore.

Comment: I have tried with a .gitignore but I wanna now why the files are auto-generated and how to get rid of them for this project and for my future projects!

Comment: Anything in the *hidden* .vs folder needs to be ignored. 
 Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520183/17034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files are generated in different scenarios and sometimes you can't really restrict Visual Studio from creating them:

### .vsidx

generated by enabling indexing for faster find. You can disable them if you want:
[How to disable that new "FileContentIndex" folder (and .vsidx files) in VS 2022 17.2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72237599/how-to-disable-that-new-filecontentindex-folder-and-vsidx-files-in-vs-2022)

### .cache

visual studio temporary files. You cannot really avoid visual studio creating these if it really needs them.
That's why they're a default add to .gitignore.

### .props and .target files

may be included when you reference NuGet packages that contain these files.
You may add them to .gitignore

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cristian! Good explaining but i forgot to add in my question that I've done some reasearch including the link you posted and it haven't been to any help unfortunatley...