# Application Publish Error: Line Suppression State Error Copying file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET Framework-4.8 while trying to publish my application in Visual Studio 2022, I got this error in the Output window:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Copying file .vs\WebService\FileContentIndex\cc5639ae-ca76-479b-b9fb-425f27681cac.vsidx to C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\MyWebService-19297545\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.vs\WebService\FileContentIndex\cc5639ae-ca76-479b-b9fb-425f27681cac.vsidx failed. The process cannot access the file '.vs\WebService\FileContentIndex\cc5639ae-ca76-479b-b9fb-425f27681cac.vsidx' because it is being used by another process.    WebService      0

Then I got this in the temp:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I found a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74210383/2668852 Disable the indexing service.

Answer (score -1):

You can take some steps to resolve this issue:

- Close Visual Studio completely and ensure there are no instances of it running in the background.
- Manually delete the contents of the `obj` folder in your project directory and any temporary files related to the publish process from Temp folder.
- Open Visual Studio, clean your solution, and then rebuild it before attempting to publish again. Go to `Build` -> `Clean Solution`, and then `Build` -> `Rebuild` Solution.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. the file is locked by the Indexing service in VS.